# Maven assembly plugin - dependendy on module of type ear in multi module project

Tags: maven, ear, maven-assembly-plugin

My question is whether there is anyway with the maven assembly plugin to reference a dependency of type ear that is not installed in the artefactory/repository.

Consider the multi-module project below with parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>parent</name>
  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>assembly</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

with ear module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <name>EAR Module</name>
</project>
```

and assembly module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>assembly</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Assembly Module</name>

  <dependencies>  
    <!-- Note - the dependencies (and their associated dependencies etc) are 
    subsequently available for assembly dependencySet includes -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
      <type>ear</type>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>  

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

with an assembly xml :

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>bundle</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>  
  <dependencySets>
    <!-- 
      Include EAR
    -->
    <dependencySet>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <outputFileNameMapping>xxxxxxxxx.ear</outputFileNameMapping>
      <outputDirectory>eardirectory</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>${pom.groupId}:module1:ear</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>

  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

From a brand new checkout with empty repository, the parent project pom fails when doing a mvn compile with the error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project assembly: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test:assembly:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact com.test:module1:ear:1.0 ...

Whereas, if I first go to the ear module and do a mvn install, then subsequent mvn compile from the parent module works perfectly.

Additionally, if the ear module was instead the standard jar module, then this issue does not exist.  Such that, if the dependency module had been of type jar, there is no need to first install it in to the local repos before doing the initial mvn compile from the parent.

Switching the dependency in the assembly pom to be of scope 'runtime' allows an initial mvn compile to succeed, however a mvn test would fail.  Setting the dependency as optional also did not succeed.

Can anyone suggest a potential solution?

I'm hoping I don't need to go down the fileSet path, or utilize the maven-dependency-plugin.  This dependency only exists in the pom so that the assembly plugin can package it / reference it.  It is not for compilation / runtime / testing.  So none of the maven dependency scopes make any sense.

Comment: The error message implies that you called maven different than `mvn compile` ... it looks more like `mvn xx:assembly` which is not the correct way. You should simply try to call maven `mvn clean package`. Furthermore the assembly module should be packaging `pom` instead of `jar`.

Comment: Hi khmarbaise;  When the assembly is changed to be of packaging of type pom, the error does NOT occur.  However, in my real application, I also have java source in this particular module (that I have called for simplification 'assembly' above) that gets put in a jar, and then packaged in the assembly zip.

Comment: Options found so far: opt 1)
do a mvn install so that the ear module (and everything else) gets installed in to the repos; Once option 1 done once, the issue won't be seen again.

opt 2) mvn package 
should work - it will compile, run tests, and create the zip, but not install any artefacts in to the repos
opt 3)
edit assembly module pom.xml and make the scope of the ear dependency to be runtime. This should allow a mvn compile to succeed (without having the ear artefact installed in the repos), but now only the mvn test will fail with the original error received due to the missing dependency

Comment: ... and option 4) split assembly module in to two separate modules; one for compilation of java src and generation/packaging of jar, and the second module purely for assembly and of packaging type pom